# Interpretting COMMAND column of `ps aux | grep redis`

Tags: ps

When I run `ps aux | grep redis`, with a running redis server, the `COMMAND` column shows `redis-server *:6379`. 6379 is the port number, but what's the `*:` for? Is it saying 'Hey, this is a port number", or does it have some other meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's listening on all available IPs - if bound to a specific IP, you'd see something like `127.0.0.1:6379`